# Escaping parentheses in string. Contains in apex

Tags: salesforce

I was trying to do some basic check using salesforce `string` object methods
Below is the sample code I'm trying to execute.

```
String myStr = 'Hello (AB)';

if(myString.contains('(AB)') {
... Do stuff
}
```

I want to look for string starting with `"(" and ending with ")"`.
I tried putting `'\(', '\\('` but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hi use can try the following code

```
String s1 = '(Yellow)';
if(String.isNotBlank(s1.substringBetween('(',')'))){
 System.debug('s1'+s1);   
}
```